# error creating stripe customer on create iOS and firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a stripe customer when the user creates an account on my IOS app. When I run the command `firebase deploy --only functions` All of my functions crash. but when I delete

```
const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
const currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'USD';



  exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  return stripe.customers.create({
  email: user.email,
  }).then((customer) => {
    return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${user.uid}/customer_id`).set(customer.id);
  });
});
```

I am receiving the error

> Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs

After going through my code I have narrowed it done to these lines. When I delete the three const, I receive the same error. If I delete the export and keep const, the same thing. My functions only push when I delete all of this. Is there something I am missing? I have seen similar questions and the answers on here have resembled the code I have so I am confused. I am checking my logs and it is not descriptive it is just repeating the same message.

The log messages I am receiving in firebase functions is,

> Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/logging'

Comment: What is the error in the functions logs that the message here is referring to?  Please edit the question and copy those messages into it.

Comment: @DougStevenson they're not desriptive at all, it is just repeating the message in terminal.

Comment: Please do still edit the question to show all of the relevant log messages generated when this code runs.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated the original question

Comment: And following the given link to learn how to inspect the logs hasn't been helpful?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have found the error! It is updated in the question. I ran npm install @google-cloud/logging and the error still persist.

Comment: You probably ran npm in the wrong directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222286/discussion-between-zach-wilcox-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: I edited the second question out.  Please ask it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a module, you have to install it first before you deploy.  From your **functions** folder, where the original package.json exists:

```
npm install @google-cloud/logging
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this may be the solution to my answer question but I am receiving the new error I have posted in my initial question.

Comment: If you have new problems after the first one, you should post those as new questions.  Stack Overflow is not meant for back-and-forth series of problems.  Stack Overflow also has a limit of one question or issue per post, in order to better help others find solutions through web searches.

Comment: My issue the entire time was that I had not installed the @google-cloud/logging. After installing this in my functions folder it compiled and ran successfully. thank you for the clarity.